# Asp.net display column in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

On Asp.Net SiteMaster, whenever a user login and is a success, the user's username is displayed at the upper right corner. The code is usually like this:

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/ManagePassword">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
```

Now what I want to happen is whenever the User successfully logged in, the Fullname of the User will be posted.

For this to happen, I basically configured default database of Asp.Net under table `AspNetUser` to add additional column such as the Fullname. When I try to change the above code with `<%: Context.User.Identity.Fullname()`, I get an error

```
'IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'Fullname' and no extension method 'Fullname' accepting a first argument of type 'IIdentity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I make the column Fullname populate the display name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for every user if they log in respective names should be displayed on the top right of page??

Comment: @NitsPatel Yes. That's it Sir.

Comment: Check my code if any further assistance let me know

Comment: If you add public property Fullname in your class you can call it Context.User.Identity.Fullname like property not like method

Comment: @erdiyılmaz The problem is I can't locate the class file of the Identity.

Comment: Did you override identity class

Comment: @erdiyılmaz I can't find it. I was only able to override the database using migration then updating the database

Comment: @MervinJoseph as you mention  nav-bar check my update code you need to add one more web form for logout your session I have mentioned in my code

Comment: @NitsPatel Sir I am prompted with page not redirecting when user is null.

Comment: what error you are getting may i know?

Comment: @NitsPatel Page not redirecting. It is like it can't detect my Project.

Comment: must sure your page name must and should be Default.aspx

Comment: use breakpoint on your page load and then debug the code page not redirecting is your else section working or not??

Comment: @NitsPatel Name is Default.aspx

Comment: have you add this code into your master page??

Comment: @MervinJoseph User_ID should be your table employee_Number and Employee_Name should be Employee name both should be match with your table if everything is perfect and still you dint get then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In master page add :

```
  <nav class="header-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-with-menu navbar-without-dd-arrow fixed-top navbar-semi-light">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-container content">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbar-mobile">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto float-left">
                        <li class="nav-item mobile-menu d-md-none mr-auto"><a class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs" href="#"><i class="ft-menu font-large-1"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><a class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs" href="#"><i class="ft-menu"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><a class="nav-link nav-link-expand" href="#"><i class="ficon ft-maximize"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-right">

                        <li class="nav-item"><span class="user-name text-bold-700 ml-1">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control" Style="background: none !important; color: white !important; border: none!important"></asp:Label></span></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item">

                            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-user-link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="avatar avatar-online">
                                    <img src="../../images/Admin.png" alt="Admin" />
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <div class="arrow_box_right">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Logout.aspx"><i class="ft-power"></i>Logout</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

C# code:

You should check session value is session exists then it will display name or else if session null then redirect to login page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Session["User_ID"] == null)
       {
         Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
       }
       else
       {
         UserName.Text = Session["Employee_Name"].ToString() + " (" + Session["User_ID"].ToString() + ")";
        }
     }
```

Comment: I think this will populate a certain Textbox or Label, how can I do it in the nav-bar?